# What is the word for someone who doesnt feel "tiredness" ,and barely sleeps

Tags: word-request

I have -rapid-adhd but I know it's not the reason.  I never feel tired I always have a constant bursting energy which last basically 24-7 . The only way I can sleep is with a high dosage of melatonin and clonidine.

Comment: Are you asking for a medical term, something to describe the feeling of being awake, or something to describe a person who is awake most of the time? Do you want a noun or an adjective?

Comment: Some might describe you as hyperactive.